# Show the intersection of 2 subspace topologies is a subspace

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

### Background

The following problem is out of my head. You can refer to *Topology Without Tears* by Sidney A. Morris for definitions:

> Theorem
>
> Let (X $\tau$) Y,Z $\subseteq X $ be a subspace of X with thier
> respective topologies inherited from X.
> Show $Y\cap Z $ is a subspace  .

### My Understanding

${\tau}_Y$={Y$\cap$ O:O$\in\tau$} and ${\tau}_Z$={Z$\cap$ O:O$\in\tau$}

$\exists$ U open in Y s.t U=Y$\cap O$

$\exists$ V open in Z s.t V=Z$\cap O$

Then

U$\cap V$ =(Y$\cap O )\cap( Z\cap O$)=(Y$\cap$ Z)$\cap$ O

Since Y ,Z are sets, they are subspaces of X
Hence Y$\cap Z $ is a subspace too

Comment: Your Question isn't quite clear, as when you say "All sets are on usual topology."  At best you are asking about the subset $Y\cap Z$ and the topology it inherits from $X$.  But the open neighborhoods inside $Y\cap Z$ are not generally the open neighborhoods inside both the subspace topologies of $Y$ and $Z$ considered as subsets of $X$.  Note that any nonempty subset of $X$ inherits a well-defined subspace topology from $X$.

Comment: I will erase that statement. I saw an YouTube video on proving the subspace topology https://youtu.be/cPgBbRFUGBg. So what type of neighborhoods are in Y$\cap Z$ that are not either of them. I assumed otherwise.

Comment: Let's suppose that $X$ is the real numbers with the usual metric topology, that $Y$ is the interval $[0,1)$ and $Z$ is $(-1,0]$.  So $Y\cap Z = \{0\}$ contains only a single point.  The open sets of that intersection's subspace topology are $\{0\}$ and the empty set.  While the empty set is open in the real numbers as well as $Y$ and $Z$, the singleton set $\{0\}$ is not open in any of those.

Comment: You continue to claim (or ask?) that "$Y\cap Z$ is a subspace of $X$".  I wonder if you appreciate the distinction between $Y,Z$ as subsets of $X$ and the topology they inherit from $X$ which are called the respective *subspace topologies*.  Recall the notation $(X, \tau)$ which designates the enclosing topological space as the pairing of the set $X$ with a family of open sets (satisfying certain conditions that make it a topology).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made up this problem yourself I believe (I couldn't find it in the mentioned book), so the problem is unclear. An interpretation:

$Y \cap Z $ can inherit the subspace topology from $Y$, from $Z$ and from $X$ itself. The result is the same in all cases:

$O \subseteq Y \cap Z$ open when seen from $X$, means that we can write $O = O' \cap (X \cap Y)$ where $O'$ is open in $X$. But then $(O'\cap Y) \in \mathcal{T}_Y$ and $(O' \cap Y) \cap Z = O$ and so $O$ is also open seen as a subspace of $Y$, and similarly from $\mathcal{T}_Z$.

It also follows from exercise 4 in paragraph 4.1 where subspaces are first introduced.

Comment: +1 for finding a good interpretation of the Question!

Comment: If Y,Z ⊂X and (X, ) is a topology show that Y∩ is a topology in X @Henno Brandsma

Comment: @Homer That's a nonsensical statement: $Y \cap Z$ is a set, not a topology.

Comment: Is it possible to show the intersection of two subspaces topologies is a subspace?. That is what it says in the title@Henno Brandsma

Comment: @Homer any subset of $X$ is a subspace. There is nothing to prove.

Comment: So there intersection is a subspace too correct? @Henno Brandsma

Comment: @Homer it’s a subset of $X$ so yes